# Differentiating Lines in Lattice Using Parallelplot

Tags: r, lattice

here is my data:

```
basketball <- structure(list(Team = c("Golden State Warriors", "Golden State Warriors", 
"Golden State Warriors", "Golden State Warriors", "Golden State Warriors", 
"Golden State Warriors", "Golden State Warriors", "Cleveland Cavaliers", 
"Cleveland Cavaliers", "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Cleveland Cavaliers", 
"Cleveland Cavaliers", "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Cleveland Cavaliers"
), Players = c("Stephen Curry", "Kevin Durant", "Draymond Green", 
"Klay Thompson", "Zaza Pachulia", "Andre Iguodala", "David West", 
"Lebron James", "Kyrie Irving", "Kevin Love", "Richard Jefferson", 
"Chris Andersen", "J.r. Smith", "Iman Shumpert"), `3 points` = c(286, 
64, 111, 239, 0, 74, 4, 120, 157, 144, 66, 4, 163, 67), `3 points Attempts` = c(646, 
159, 329, 545, 3, 212, 20, 339, 378, 392, 155, 13, 426, 196), 
    `2 points` = c(367, 174, 228, 363, 240, 157, 319, 504, 421, 
    269, 78, 116, 152, 126), `2 points Attempt` = c(695, 308, 
    436, 754, 526, 284, 666, 940, 857, 560, 169, 194, 329, 275
    ), `Free Throws` = c(308, 146, 132, 225, 126, 68, 119, 375, 
    315, 258, 78, 76, 54, 43), `Free Throws Attempts` = c(337, 
    171, 200, 256, 160, 114, 161, 528, 365, 321, 114, 114, 72, 
    64), `Total Rebounds` = c(341, 178, 647, 247, 500, 257, 449, 
    416, 237, 731, 183, 299, 218, 224), Steals = c(163, 24, 123, 
    87, 80, 89, 48, 109, 114, 51, 32, 26, 82, 81), `Blocks ` = c(16, 
    25, 99, 60, 21, 25, 48, 49, 20, 39, 11, 61, 22, 16), `Personal Fouls` = c(158, 
    40, 253, 122, 170, 100, 160, 135, 146, 140, 115, 88, 163, 
    138), `Total points` = c(1900, 686, 921, 1668, 606, 604, 
    769, 1743, 1628, 1228, 432, 320, 847, 496)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .Names = c("Team", 
"Players", "3 points", "3 points Attempts", "2 points", "2 points Attempt", 
"Free Throws", "Free Throws Attempts", "Total Rebounds", "Steals", 
"Blocks ", "Personal Fouls", "Total points"))
```

There are two teams in the data above (Cleveland and Golden State Warriors). My parallel plot right now looks like this:

[parallelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoEWO.jpg)

The code for the graph above is:

```
library(lattice)
parallelplot(basketball, horizontal.axis = F, col = '#000000')
```

I've tried to put different colors for the two teams with:

```
library(lattice)
reading_colors <- c()
for (i in 1:length(basketball$Team)){
    if (basketball$Team[i] > 7) {
        col <- "#000000"
    } else { 
        col <- "#cccccc"
    }
    reading_colors <- c(reading_colors,col)
}
parallelplot(basketball, horizontal.axis = F, col = reading_colors)
```

However, when I access reading_colors, this is the values (the loop is not working):

```
c("#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", 
"#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", 
"#000000", "#000000")
```

Would appreciate any feedback on why this is not working and can someone please  help me differentiate my lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
parallelplot(basketball, horizontal.axis = F, groups=basketball$Team)
```

Each group will have a different default color.

EDIT to control colors -

With `trellis.par.set` you can define the group colors:

```
trellis.par.set(list(superpose.line=list(col=c("#000000","#cccccc"))))

parallelplot(basketball, horizontal.axis = F,groups=basketball$Team,lwd=2)
```

Or you can do it directly in the `parallelplot` call:

```
parallelplot(basketball, horizontal.axis = F,groups=basketball$Team,lwd=2,
  par.settings=list(superpose.line=list(col=c("#000000","#cccccc"))))
```

(Note the gray color is pretty light so I added`lwd=2` to make the lines thicker.)

Comment: Yes it works! But are there any ways to modify the colors?

Answer (score 0):

`basketball$Team > 7` is always true.

```
> basketball$Team > 7
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Therfore, the color is always the same.

Perhaps it easier to use a colormap e.g. `rainbow`

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendation on how to fix the loop?

Comment: Why do you need a loop at all? Use DaveTurek's method or set any color you want (with `rainbow`)?

Comment: I was thinking a loop might be useful if i want to categorize based on the median of other variables? Will have a look at rainbow. Any good reference?

Comment: Just type ` ?rainbow`

Comment: Define some new variable based on the median you want and use that as the `groups` variable.